# Understanding assembly from a gcc output

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm doing a high school course about computer fundamentals and I'm trying to understand assembly code and created a hello world in C and compiled it in assembly code. I understand that "mov r0,r3" moves data from register 3 to register 0. However, how do I figure out what what the value of r3 is?

Below is the assembly code that I'm using for my understanding from:

```
.arch armv6
.eabi_attribute 27, 3
.eabi_attribute 28, 1
.fpu vfp
.eabi_attribute 20, 1
.eabi_attribute 21, 1
.eabi_attribute 23, 3
.eabi_attribute 24, 1
.eabi_attribute 25, 1
.eabi_attribute 26, 2
.eabi_attribute 30, 6
.eabi_attribute 34, 1
.eabi_attribute 18, 4
.file   "hello.c"
.section    .rodata
.align  2
.LC0:
    .ascii  "Hello World\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global main
    .type   main, %function
main:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    stmfd   sp!, {fp, lr}
    add     fp, sp, #4
    ldr     r0, .L2
    bl      printf
    mov     r0, r3
    ldmfd   sp!, {fp, pc}
.L3:
    .align  2
.L2:
    .word   .LC0
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Raspbian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

Below is my C code:

```
// Hello World program in C

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Debugger...............

Comment: `main` is a function. This sounds oversimplified, but it's a function with arguments. The first n arguments are passed in registers. The actual register-argument-assignment depends on your compiler ABI. The statement `mov r0,r3` indicates that `main` probably returns one of the arguments. What's the C code of the main function? It's possible that the ABI defines that the register R3 will be returned as it was at function entry. So it's nothing that have to be related to the function `printf`.

Comment: When you look at a C statement like `x=y`, how do you figure out what the value of y is? Same thing here.

Comment: the generated code you see can't run by its own: it must be linked with more code, the one containing the caller to `main`; from that you would discover how `r3` and `r0` will be conventionally used. 
(I don't know anything about ARM and Raspberry Pi, about which I think you can ask [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).)

Comment: I've added my C code in to my question. So how does this work? Is the value of r3  "Hello World"?

Comment: [godbolt gives an identical output but with an extra line](https://godbolt.org/g/6LkDbw) that clarifies the use of `r3`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom - so in your godbolt example  `r3` has the return value from `main()` and it's being put into `r0`. `main()` with no explicit return has an implied `return 0`.  But in the OP's example there's no guarantee that `r3` contains 0 - maybe he is using a compiler that's pre-C99 so it's just returning an arbitrary value?

Comment: do you have to do a main and printf?  other functions would be easier starting points to understand  like unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b ) { return(a+b); }   you also need to understand the calling convention that parameters are passed in in registers.

Comment: you didnt explicitly return anything so the compiler appears free to make up whatever garbage return it wants...

Comment: @MichaelBurr Looks like you're right. If you add `-std=c99` to options at your godbolt link, an explicit `mov r3, #0` is added to the output.

Answer (score 3):

Use the GNU Debugger, "gdb"!
`gdb --args ./store01` starts the GNU Debugger.
It should act something like a console.
You exit by typing `quit`.
But of course you want to run the programm step by step and check the register contetns. So type `start`, which jumpes to main() and skips the initialization stuff. 
Then type `disassemble` or `disas` to show the assebler you're running.
Now run the program instruction per instruction per typing `stepi`.
And now the interesting part: type `info registers r3` and watch the output! 
And another fantastic thing: you can CHANGE the values runtime: try `p $r0 = 2`.
That's not all.
Here's the official documentation:https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/ 
And a good, small and useful tutorial: http://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/12/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-4

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's break it down.

`stmfd sp!, {fp, lr}`

STMFD means "STore Multiple Full Descending". Essentially, it's using the register `sp` as a descending stack pointer and placing the registers `fp` and `lr` on the stack, in that order. `fp` is the frame pointer, `lr` is the link register (holds the return address, important later).

`add fp, sp, #4`

Sets the frame pointer register to be equal to sp+4 (points to where `fp` was just stored). This is an artifact of compilation without optimization.

`ldr r0, .L2`

This is shorthand for loading the 32-bit value stored at address `.L2` (which in this case is the address of `.LC0`, the string (well, char array) `"Hello World!\000"`) into register `r0`.

`bl printf`

Assembled by calling the `printf` function on the null-terminated string `"Hello World"`. Recall that the pointer to this array was just loaded into `r0`.  In general, GCC uses registers r0-r3 as the first, second, third, and fourth arguments to functions, respectively. Additional arguments are stored on the stack as needed.

`mov r0, r3`

This is an indicator of a bug in your code, which this version of GCC did not catch. Basically, your function returns a type (assumed to be `int` because you never specified otherwise), but you never specified a return value. Thus the return value is whatever happened to be in `r3`, which is undefined.

`ldmfd sp!, {fp, pc}`

This is the reverse of the `stmfd` instruction compiled at the beginning of the function. But instead of loading into `fp, lr`, we're loading into `fp, pc`. This causes the original value of `lr` to be moved directly into the program counter `pc`. `pc` is a special register in that it points to the next instruction executed. Any time `pc` is set to a value, the CPU immediately starts executing code pointed to by that value. This property is used to `return` to the calling routine, since the ARM instruction set does not have an explicit `ret` operation.